# Exception sending an image to my application

Tags: android

I have this Exception when I try to send an image from "ES file explorer" to my application using share option. I don't know what sort of exception it is and I don't know what is the cause of it.

```
04-15 19:15:33.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-15 19:15:33.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6004):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi did you find a way to solve this error? I get this error when I try to pick a file using an intent to samsung's built-in file explorer (My Files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result
```

This is just from reading it.. but it looks like it has a flag to forward the result to you, but it also wants something back, you arne't doing that I'm assuming so that would cause the error. You need to look into how "ES file explorer" sends it information and then that might help. Aside from that not sure. Hope this can get you in the right direction.